# React passing a variable object to setState vs. an anonymous object to setState

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, fetch, setstate

I was having issues rendering a chart after state has been updated by the data fetched from an API.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Bar, Line, Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class PopChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'AAA',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: []
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  url = 'api_url';

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.url)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          httpStatusCode: response.status,
          httpStatusOk: response.ok
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else if (response.status === 404) {
          // Not found
          throw Error('HTTP 404, Not found');
        } else {
          throw Error(`HTTP ${response.status}, ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log('Then function');

        this.setChartProperties(responseData);
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  setChartProperties = data => {
    this.setChartData(data);
    // this.setChartXAxis(data);
  };

  setChartData = data => {
    let hours = data.map(event => event.hour);
    hours = hours.splice(0, 10);
    const { chartData } = { ...this.state };

    const chartDataUpdate = chartData;
    chartDataUpdate['datasets'].data = hours;

    // Working version
    // this.setState({
    //   chartData: {
    //     labels: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    //     datasets: [
    //       {
    //         label: 'AAA',
    //         data: hours,
    //         backgroundColor: []
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   }
    // });

    // Not working version
    this.setState({ chartData: chartDataUpdate });
  };



  render() {
   <Bar data={this.state.chartData} />;
  }
}
```

At first I thought the issue was regarding the asynchronous nature of `fetch()` and the `<Bar/>` component from Chart.js was being rendered before the state got a chance to get updated. However, when I logged out the state, on the console it showed my state with the changed values. However, the chart did not display any of the values.

When I called `setState()` and passed an anonymous object (refer to the commented out working version of `setState()`), the chart displayed the values.

Why does it not work when I stored the fetched data into a variable and pass it as an argument for `setState()`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that `state.chartData.datasets` is an array, but in `setChartData` you're setting data on the array not one of its elements.

This:

`chartDataUpdate['datasets'].data = hours;`

Should be:

`chartDataUpdate['datasets'][0].data = hours;`